# StripFilter in Liferay 6.1.1 GA2 doesn't strip white space

Tags: liferay, servlet-filters

We're using the StripFilter property in our production systems:

```
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter=true
```

but on the most pages the markup isn't properly stripped (some parts like navigation has massive whitespaces, others like head are fine) or worst case the whole markup is not stripped!

Those non stripped pages have up to 20k lines of source code (mostly blank), which causes poor performance in browsers.

Mostly appears when pages requested as guest user, but this is not reproducible.
Also when we undeploy all webapps, this problem occurs.

How we can investigate this problem?
Is this a common issue?

Answer (score 0):

If some part of the beginning of your page is actually stripped and the rest is not, then the filter tripped over your html. Maybe you have an error in your html code. Or the strip was simply too stupid.

Remember that you must (because of the filter) close **input** tags with a /> If you do not, the filter looks up the next /> and does not strip anything between!

Example

```
<input name="bla">    
<p> hello      world,  
<br /> 
<span> you are </span>  
           beautiful. </p>
```

This will lead to the following output, because the 
 closes the

```
<input name="bla">    
<p> hello      world,  
<br /><span>you are</span> beautiful. </p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's all over not stripped. There's even whitespace before the doctype definition.

Comment: Does it only happen on the first page ( eg. /web/bla/ ) or on all pages? Our current setup only has issues with the front page